# c# console app, process naming using a variable

Tags: c#

I have a c# console app that creates a process for 15 digital cameras to takes and downloads pictures on command.
Currently it is hardcoded for 16 cameras and I would like to have it ask the user for the amount of camera's and then create that amount of processes/connections.

Here is an example of the code that connects to 3 cameras:

```
    Process takePic2;
    takePic2 = new Process();
    takePic2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    //takePic2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    takePic2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    takePic2.StartInfo.FileName = chdkLocation;
    string config2 = @"-i -c""-d=\\.\libusb0%-0002%-%-0x04a9%-0x3248""";
    takePic2.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(config2);
    takePic2.Start();

    StreamWriter sw2 = takePic2.StandardInput;
    //sw2.WriteLine("list");
    sw2.WriteLine("rec");
    //sw2.WriteLine("shoot");

    Process takePic3;
    takePic3 = new Process();
    takePic3.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    //takePic3.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    takePic3.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    takePic3.StartInfo.FileName = chdkLocation;
    string config3 = @"-i -c""-d=\\.\libusb0%-0003%-%-0x04a9%-0x3248""";
    takePic3.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(config3);
    takePic3.Start();

    StreamWriter sw3 = takePic3.StandardInput;
    //sw3.WriteLine("list");
    sw3.WriteLine("rec");
    //sw3.WriteLine("shoot");

    Process takePic4;
    takePic4 = new Process();
    takePic4.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    //takePic4.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    takePic4.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    takePic4.StartInfo.FileName = chdkLocation;
    string config4 = @"-i -c""-d=\\.\libusb0%-0004%-%-0x04a9%-0x3248""";
    takePic4.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(config4);
    takePic4.Start();

    StreamWriter sw4 = takePic4.StandardInput;
    //sw4.WriteLine("list");
    sw4.WriteLine("rec");
    //sw4.WriteLine("shoot");
```

and here is the code that takes the pictures and downloads them:

```
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("type shoot to take a picture:"); // Prompt
        string commandInput = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user

        if (commandInput == "s")
        {
            sw1.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw2.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw3.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw4.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw5.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw6.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw7.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw8.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw9.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw10.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw11.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw12.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw13.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw14.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw15.WriteLine("shoot");
            sw16.WriteLine("shoot");
        }

        if (commandInput == "dl")
        {
            sw1.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera1/ -rm");
            sw2.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera2/ -rm");
            sw3.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera3/ -rm");
            sw4.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera4/ -rm");
            sw5.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera5/ -rm");
            sw6.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera6/ -rm");
            sw7.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera7/ -rm");
            sw8.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera8/ -rm");
            sw9.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera9/ -rm");
            sw10.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera10/ -rm");
            sw11.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera11/ -rm");
            sw12.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera12/ -rm");
            sw13.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera13/ -rm");
            sw14.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera14/ -rm");
            sw15.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera15/ -rm");
            sw16.WriteLine("imdl -ddir=/HDimages/camera16/ -rm");
        }
    }
```

I already have it asking the user for the numbers of cameras to connect to and I have it creating a for loop for that number. My question is how do I set the process name to increment with the for loop i variable so it would be "Process takepic+cameranumber"

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of cameras:"); // Prompt
    string inputCameraQuantity = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user
    int cameraQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(inputCameraQuantity);

    string chdkLocation = @"C:\scancode\chdk\chdkptp.exe";

    for (int i = 1; i <= cameraQuantity; i++)
    {

        string cameranumber = Convert.ToString(i);
        Process takepic;
        //Process takepic+cameranumber;
        takepic = new Process();
        takepic.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        takepic.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        takepic.StartInfo.FileName = chdkLocation;

        if (cameraQuantity < 10)
        {
            cameranumber = "0" + Convert.ToString(i);
        }
        else { cameranumber = Convert.ToString(i); }

        string configA = @"-i -c""-d=\\.\libusb0%-000";
        string configB = @"%-%-0x04a9%-0x3248""";
        string configC = configA + cameranumber + configB;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.   Instead what you can do is put it in a List.

```
 var Cameras = new List<Process>()
 for (int i = 1; i <= cameraQuantity; i++)
    {
        Process takepic;
        //Process takepic+cameranumber;
        takepic = new Process();
        Cameras.Add(takepic);
```

then you can get them by

```
Cameras[0]. //whatever
```

or

If you want them named, put them in a dictionary

```
var Cameras = new Dictionary<string, Process>()

     for (int i = 1; i <= cameraQuantity; i++)
            {
                Process takepic;
                //Process takepic+cameranumber;
                takepic = new Process();
                Cameras.Add("takepic"+cameranumber, takepic);
```

then get them

```
Cameras["takepic1"]. // whatever
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked and it now connects to X number of cameras. I have a follow up question. How do I use the same process for the streamwriter portion? I tried to follow the same logic for the processes but I am stuck on creating the streamwriter connection.

Comment: Here is the code:
'
            var Cameras = new List<Process>();
            var camera_connection = new List<StreamWriter>();
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= cameraQuantity; i2++)
            {
                Process takepicdynamic;
                takepicdynamic = new Process();
                Cameras.Add(takepicdynamic);


                //create streamwriter input for each camera process
                StreamWriter sw1 = takepicdynamic.StandardInput;
                sw1.WriteLine("rec");
'